# How to fetch Strapi content to my bigcommerce theme?

Tags: shopify, bigcommerce, strapi, headless-cms

I am very new to Strapi and I have bigcommerce theme where I should implement content from Strapi.

How can I import content from Strapi to my bigcommerce theme?

In my bigcommerce theme I have config.json where I have these fields :

```
> - I doubt that this is not correctly set, because I dont see other way to connect strapi with my bigcommerce theme.
> 
>     "settings": {
>     "strapi_base_url": "what should I put here?(is it url with my cms admin strapi url?)",
>     "integration_server_base_url": "And same question, what is integration_server_base_url, where I can find it?",
>     "google_captcha_key": "/",
>     "bc_app_client_id": "/",
>     "google_site_verification": "/",
>     ...
>     }
```

In short I need to populate a theme with content from Strapi.

Thanks on your time, and every advice would be nice!

Answer (score 1):

Big thanks for your answer! My problem was that i couldn't get/display the strap content in the bigcommerce theme which i setup locally. I managed to start a project/bigcommerce theme locally with all the content from strapi. I used stencil init and finally get job done! **Reason for not getting Strapi content locally in my BC theme was name of folder and path was not appropriate. I had in the name of the folder "+ ( ) -) and that was a reason** :D. I spent a couple of days, now is all ok! :) Big thanks again for help! :) – Dejan just now   Edit   Delete

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this, I believe you’ll have to integrate Strapi to the BigCommerce theme - likely using the Scripts API and this Strapi doc: https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/content-api/integrations.html

Depending on what you’re wanting to import into BC, the method could be different.
For example, with importing products to your BC store, you can do a mass import with BC with an external csv file. So if you can export that data into this format the import process is lined out for you here:
[Video on Importing Products](https://support.bigcommerce.com/s/article/Importing-and-Exporting-CSVs-Video)
[Import/Export Overview](https://support.bigcommerce.com/s/article/Import-Export-Overview)

However, that example is with a store rather than a theme. Importing to a theme may be a little more complex.

If I may ask -- what all types of content are you trying to export from Strapi?
I’m looking into [their docs](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/getting-started/introduction.html) to see what is possible, as well as reaching out to my team to look for some additional help. :)

Comment: Hey! Big thanks for your answer! My problem was that i couldn't get/display the strap content in the bigcommerce theme which i setup locally. I managed to start a project/bigcommerce theme locally with all the content from strapi. I used stencil init and finally get jobe done! Reason for not getting Strapi content locally in my BC theme was name of folder and path was not appropriate. I had in the name of the folder "+ ( ) -) and that was a reason :D. I spent a couple of days, now is all ok! :) Big thanks again for help! :)